# Notification in android do not work

Tags: android, notifications

I am making notification bar in my app and this is my code :

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.notificationservicedemo;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText editMsg;
    DatePicker datePicker;
    TimePicker timePicker;
    Button btnSetNotification;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        editMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        btnSetNotification = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetNotification);

        btnSetNotification.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonSetNotification:
            String message=editMsg.getText().toString();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentHour());


            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


            intent.setClass(this, MyNotificationService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            //startService(intent);

            break;


        }
    }

}
```

MyNotificationService:

```
package com.example.notificationservicedemo;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyNotificationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnStart()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Bla bla bla", System.currentTimeMillis());

        String contentTitle="Title";
        String contentText="This is your message";
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(123, notification);
    }



}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.notificationservicedemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.notificationservicedemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service  android:name="com.example.notificationservicedemo.MyNotificationService"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Problem is that when I pick time when notification has to come up I press my button to save and then notification comes up immediately it ignores my timePicker and datePicker. What is the peoblem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution for launch a notification on android :

```
public class MyNotification {
    private NotificationManager nm;
    private Notification nf;
    private int notification_id;

    public MyNotification(Context context, Class<?> cls, int icon, CharSequence tickerText, CharSequence title, CharSequence text, int notification_id) {
        nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.cancelAll();

        Intent activity = new Intent(context, cls);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activity, 0);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent); //-> Activity open after click
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setTicker(tickerText);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(text);

        //builder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+R.raw.good)); //-> Song
        //builder.setContent(new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.note)); //-> Layout
        //builder.setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 25, 100}); // -> Vibration

        Notification nf = builder.getNotification();
        this.nf = nf;
        this.notification_id = notification_id;
    }

    public void show() {
        this.nm.notify(notification_id, nf);
    }
}
```

I hope i have helped you!